# Correct use of hyphen to prefix multiple words with one

Tags: grammaticality

I wrote:

> An open -source and -society loving person

and had this corrected by a native English speaker to

> An open-source-and-society loving person

Which to me changes the meaning of the phrase. The first one is meant to be short-hand for prefixing both "source" and "society" with "open", while the second one does not seem to connect "society" with "open".

Is either of the forms more correct than the other? Should it be written differently all together?

Comment: This just shows that 'native speaker' is not much of a qualification, as he/she took your acceptable sentence and ruined it.

Comment: -1 Please consult a standard reference and include your research results in any question you ask. Close General Reference.

Comment: I initially googled, but didn't know what to search for, so I didn't find anything on this topic. After you comment though, I tried some more, and found out that it's called [Suspended hyphens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen#Suspended_hyphens)

Comment: @user50849 Feel free to make your comment an answer to your own question. [It's encouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). (:

Comment: @Zairja, thanks. I'm aware of that, but figured I'd get the question closed based on ΜετάEd's comment. Posted an answer now.

Answer (score 4):

The use of hyphens in my initial sentance is called [Suspended hyphens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen#Suspended_hyphens).

From wikipedia:

> A suspended hyphen (also referred to as a "hanging hyphen" or "dangling hyphen") may be used when a single base word is used with separate, consecutive, hyphenated words which are connected by "and", "or", or "to". For example, nineteenth-century and twentieth-century may be written as nineteenth- and twentieth-century.