# Usage of hypens when using two compund nouns

Tags: hyphenation, academic-writing

I was wondering about the correct usage of the hyphen in cases of the form:

> In the short- and long-run.

As opposed to:

> In the short and long-run.

Is the first case accepted?

Comment: Hello, Weierstraß Ramirez. 'in the long run' and 'In the short run' aren't usually hyphenated. For cases where hyphens _are_ used, 'suspended hyphens' have been covered before.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct use of hyphen to prefix multiple words with one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80520/correct-use-of-hyphen-to-prefix-multiple-words-with-one) Or [Does the omission of the first part of a hyphenated compound run afoul of CMoS?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/567072/does-the-omission-of-the-first-part-of-a-hyphenated-compound-run-afoul-of-chicag)? Or [Suspended hyphen in ever-expanding and -contracting gulf](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/441978/suspended-hyphen-inever-expanding-and-contracting-gulf)?